Excel min max formula interpretation
I have following formula in one of my reference book and can't understand what it means, can someone let me know the interpretation of this formula
= Min (100%, Max (0, (a2 + b2)1/2 - 10%))

What does 100% and -10% means and How to interpret entire formula

Min and max are both comparison functions. You're taking an array of values and finding the lowest value in the array (min) and the largest value in the array (max).
In your case, the min function takes the value 100% and the output of the max function.
The max function compares the values of 0 and (a2 + b2)1/2 - 10%). So lets say A2 and B2 come to a value of 4 - half of that makes it 2 then subtract 10% of that (10% is put in relation to 1, so it would come to 1.9.
So what's bigger then, 0 or 1.9? The answer is 1.9.
Whats lesser, 100% or 1.9? Well, 1.9 comes to 190%...so 100% is less than 190%.
